# Windows phone position:fixed bottom:0 doesn't work

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a mobile webpage with some sliding nav sticked on the bottom.

http://tinyurl.com/c5aauyj

On a Windows Phone the slider nav doesn't stick to the bottom, it is on top. Iphone/desktop does it correct. I really can't find whats going wrong. Somehow the position fixed doesn't work on WP??

```
.slider-text {
    background: url("../../images/bg_content.png") repeat scroll left top transparent;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 165px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
```

Comment: What happens when you change it to 0px or take it out completely?

Comment: Hmm, thats weird, I have set 0px in the stylesheet but Firebug says bottom:0; 

So I think that can't be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

windows phone 7 - both pre and post-Mango ignore fixed positioning and render fixed elements as position:static.